# Why is my Spring ContextRefreshed event called twice?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring ApplicationListener bean registered to listen for ContextRefreshed events. For some odd reason though, I get *two* calls to the `onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent)` method at the completion of the context initialization. Is this normal behavior or is it indicative of a problem with my configuration? I'm using Jetty 8 for my Servlet container.

My relevant web.xml configuration is as follows

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/spring/spring-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Even though you did not specify a contextConfigLocation for your DispatcherServlet it still creates a child context and the second refreshed event is for that context.  Use event.getApplicationContext() to find out which context the event is for.

Comment: That was it! Using either the `id` or `displayName` property of the ApplicationContext I can now distinguish between the two events.

Comment: Or if you @Autowire the appContext (or implement ApplicationContextAware) you can compare that appContext versus the one in the event.

Comment: @Andre A noob's question: How to access ID or displayName from ContextRefreshedEvent?

Comment: Figured it out. By casting ContextRefreshedEvent.getSource() to ApplicationContext and then calling getDisplayName()/getId() on that.

Answer (score 2):

it happened to me as well, on a different event-listener. (`ApplicationListener<AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent>`)

I suspected the **ContextLoaderListener**, and when I removed the declaration from the web.xml, the app was working properly. Then I had to figure out what is its purpose, of the ContextLoaderListener...

[Role/Purpose of ContextLoaderListener in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815339/role-purpose-of-contextloaderlistener-in-spring)

the interesting answer there is:

> ContextLoaderListener is optional. Just to make a point here: you can
>   boot up a Spring application without ever configuring
>   ContextLoaderListener ...just the basic minimum web.xml with
>   DispatcherServlet

Answer (score 1):

It looks like bug.

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6589

If you are using 3.0 try it on the latest available release which is 3.05.

Comment: Ok, we're using 3.0.4 so I'll give 3.0.5 a shot and report back my findings.

Comment: Bah, upgraded to 3.0.5 and it's still an issue.

Comment: Even 3.1 has the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too but fixed it. I was injecting the dataSource into my DAO (and instantiating a JdbcTemplate with it)....but I also had a Spring bean configured for JDBCTemplate.

I should have been injecting my DAO with the jdbcTemplate...that avoids the duplicate.