# I can't seem to get an implementation of Spring's Lifecycle working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I need something to happen immediately after Spring's application context is loaded. As I understand it, I need to create an implementation of Lifecycle and put a bean reference inside the context. So I have something like this in my context:

```
<bean id="mySpringLifecycle" class="com.my.project.MySpringLifecycle" />
```

The class looks something like this:

```
public class MySpringLifecycle implements Lifecycle {

    @Override
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("The lifecycle has started.");
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I get no errors, but MySpringLifecycle never prints out "The lifecycle has started.", and my application starts just fine.

**EDIT:**

This is the fixed code:

```
public class MySpringLifecycle implements SmartLifecycle {

    private volatile boolean isRunning = false;

    @Override
    public boolean isAutoStartup() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(Runnable r) {
        System.out.println("STOPPED RUNNABLE!!!");
        isRunning = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("STARTED!!!");
        isRunning = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        System.out.println("STOPPED!!!");
        isRunning = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return isRunning;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPhase() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

As a side note I also wanted to mention an alternative solution that I may use as well. I have the following in my web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The ContextLoaderListener has a method on it called contextInitialized. So what I did was created my own implementation and added that to the web.xml instead. In my implementation I extended ContextLoaderListener, provided an override for the contextInitialized method, called super for that method first, and then executed my own functionality. This gets executed only once, and appears to work well.

Comment: Quoted from http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-processor

As you can see the stop method defined by SmartLifecycle accepts a callback. Any implementation must invoke that callback's run() method after that implementation's shutdown process is complete.

Comment: What if your class additionally extends another class. In addition the mentioned class is defined in spring <bean="myBean"><constructor-arg ref="beanA"/><property name="name1" ref="beanB"/>. How to instantiate these parameters in your class example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two ways to do this:

1. Implement `SmartLifecycle` instead of `Lifecycle` and make sure to return `true` from `isAutoStartup()`.
2. Implement `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>`.  In this case there is only one method to implement instead of 6 for `SmartLifecycle`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the ContextRefreshedEvent gets called several times during startup, not just once. I tried ContextStartedEvent, but that doesn't fire on application startup because the default life cycle doesn't appear to call start().

Comment: When I implement SmartLifecycle the only thing getting called is the public void stop(Runnable r) override. There are obviously some implementation details I'm missing to make this work.

Comment: Make sure that `isRunning()` returns `false` until `start()` is called.  `stop()` won't be called unless `isRunning()` returns true.

Comment: Re: ContextRefreshedEvent being called multiple times, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164573/why-is-my-spring-contextrefreshed-event-called-twice/6165557#6165557

Comment: That was it. I will post the fix above. Thanks!

Comment: No one seems to explain exactly why the start() method doesnt get called when implementing Lifecycle. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

If you modify `MySpringLifecycle` to implement [SmartLifecycle](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/SmartLifecycle.html) instead of [Lifecycle](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/Lifecycle.html), System.outs in your snippet will be printed as you expect them to be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you [might](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-processor) need a `LifecycleProcessor` in addition to one-or-more `Lifecycle` objects.

Comment: No - a DefaultLifecyleProcessor gets added to the context automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by 'immediately after Spring's application context is loaded.', an implementation of InitializingBean might be what you are looking for.
LifeCycle might be too much low-level.

Comment: `InitializingBean#afterPropertiesSet()` is called before the context is fully constructed, so bad things can happen if you depend on another bean.